# ACM Certificate with Wildcard does not Work for the Newly Created Subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager, aws-acm

My recent infrastructure had the following setup:

- A domain on Route53 as `example.com`.
- Several subdomains e.g. `blog.example.com`, `dev.example.com` etc.
- A certificate on ACM with `*.example.com` as its entry.

Everything worked as expected, until I was required to add another domain, e.g. `abc.dev.example.com`. SSL doesn't work on this newly created subdomain.

My previous experience suggests creating a new certificate for this new subdomain, it has worked for me earlier as well. But it doesn't seem to be a best practice. Can I refresh/update my current certificate to accommodate the new subdomain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because wildcard SSL cert can only support **one subdomain level**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html):

> When you request a wild card certificate, the asterisk (*) must be in the leftmost position of the domain name and **can protect only one subdomain level**. For example, *.example.com can protect login.example.com, and test.example.com, but it **cannot protect** test.login.example.com.

So in your case you need new certificate for `*.dev.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction. I have created a domain with one subdomain level now. Unfortunately, when I open the URL it's still not secure. Do I need to refresh my certificate somehow to accommodate it as well?

Comment: @amsh No problem. You can't updated existing ssl cert to add a subdomain. You have to create new one.